# Is there any simple way in PHP 5.x to echo any type of data on a RecordSet?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, recordset

So this is it.

I wrote a SQL statement dumb as duck, like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

Basically I want:

1. Do a generic SELECT statement;
2. Loop through the Resulset;
3. Print the metadata "name" as Table Headers.
4. Loop through Resultset again;
5. Print each record as table row.
6. Print each field as table column.
7. How to test the data, in the field so I can properly echo this data as string? I'm not sure if I made myself clear.

I can't know what data will be returned form the statements, previously.
This is motivated after trying print DateTime fields, and getting an error.

This is my PHP code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM client";      

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);    

    if( $stmt === false) 
    {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $num_fields = sqlsrv_num_fields($stmt);

    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
    // Output Headers - In SQL Server

    echo '<tr  style="font-size:12px">';
    foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata( $stmt ) as $fieldMetadata ) 
    {
        foreach( $fieldMetadata as $name => $value) 
        {
            if ($name == "Name"){
                echo  "<td><strong>" . "$value" . "</td></strong>";
            }
        }

    }
    echo "</tr>";

    // Output fields data, after fetch new row.
    while ( sqlsrv_fetch ( $stmt ) ) 
    {
        // \echo '<tr class="small"  style="font-size:10px">';
        echo '<tr class="small">';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
        {
            echo '<td class="text-nowrap">';
            print_r (sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, $i));
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Please, correct me about any bad practice, or stupid coding... I'm a complete newbie here.

Comment: Note that in the first loop you have put the `strong` closing tag outside the `td`. Also, you can just write **echo  "<td><strong>$value</strong></td>"** without dot operator.

Comment: Thanks, @trincot, I wrote this script in a little rush... Already fixed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [specify the data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296208%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of the result value, and choose the `string` data type, as follows:

```
print_r (sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, $i, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING( SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR)));
```

Alternatively, instead of calling `sqlsrv_fetch` and `sqlsrv_get_field`, use [`sqlsrv_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) as that automatically converts all retrieved data to `string`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right direction... I really appreciate that; I'm reading the documentation right now... But just for a brief clarifying, this specified data type (SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING()), can implicitly convert the Datetime data, to an default pre-formatted string? Is that it?

Comment: Yes that's it. In the mean time I have also described an alternative. Your preference might go to that one as it looks less obscure.

Comment: Thank you very much.
That worked fine. :)

Sorry for being late.